# estimate Markov chain mean transition time

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, parameter-estimation, transition-matrix

Assume a continuous time Markov chain which is run through in one direction and finally absorbed at the last state

$1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow n $

The transition matrix is

$\begin{bmatrix} 
-\lambda_1 & \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\lambda_2 & \lambda_2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & ... & ... & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\lambda_{n-1} & \lambda_{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Now suppose we have different realizations $i$ of this chain. For each realization we know the initial state $a_i$, and the state $b_i$ at some (known) time $t_i$ afterwards.

Is there an efficient way to estimate the mean total transition time

$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\lambda_j}$

from this data?

Comment: So you don't always start at state $1$?

Comment: Exactly, it is started at different states.

Comment: If it’s absorbed by the last state, then shouldn’t the last row be $[0,0,\dots,0,1]$?

Comment: I don't think so - it's a continuous Markov chain so the rows should sum up to 0.